# Get Method by CustomAttribute and then Invoke

Tags: c#

With a massive learning curve into Custom Attributes and Reflection, I still seem to be struggling. Could anyone help me out with this one?

Basically I want to invoke a method based on it's attribute.

This is the CustomAttribute that decorates a method (it will only ever be one method):
**[ControllerName(Name="blog")]**

```
public static string GetContent(string controllerName, string singleItemName = "") 
{
    string returnVal = null;
    //Get the class type
    Type thisType = typeof(ContentFacade);

    //Get member info 
    System.Reflection.MemberInfo info = typeof(ContentFacade);

    Loop through attributes
    foreach (object attrib in info.GetCustomAttributes(true))
    {
        //if the attribute matches the param controller name
        //then invoke
        if (attrib == controllerName)
        { 
            //Get the method by attribute not method name
            //I dont want to get the method by MethodName
            MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(controllerName);

            //Return the value as it will be html for the end user
            returnVal = (string)theMethod.Invoke(controllerName, null);
        }
    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

Again, if possible I would like to get a method by an attribute.

Really looking forward to some help on this.

**///Edits**
Sorry I added comments in the code to illustrate the issue.
Basically I would like to:

- Get an attribute by controllerName == "blog"
- Get the method by attribute and invoke

I don't want to get the method by method name.

Regards,

Comment: What is the actual problem that you are having?

Comment: I do think that your problem is more a logical one than a "what is the name of the method". Think a little what you want to do, and everything will become easier. The Code you have posted seems to have logical problems.

Comment: @xanatos nice cryptic comment :) Care to elaborate ?

Comment: @TezWingfield Try writing what each line is doing... Your objective: `Basically I want to invoke a method based on it's attribute.`. So the solution is something like: take a `Type`, take all the methods of that type, search for a method of that type that has the attribute `ControllerNameAttribute`, look at the Name of the `ControllerNameAttribute`. If the name is the right one, execute the method. Now look at what you are doing: `info = typeof(ContentFacade);` you take a type... `foreach (object attrib in info.GetCustomAttributes(true))` and you look at its attributes. It is totally different

Comment: @xanatos I certainly agree, but maybe my logic was slightly "warped" because I said myself what if I have 200 methods and only 20 CustomAttributes ? It would be less of a performance hit if I just looped through the attributes first. BUT if it cannot be done or it just does not make sense, then so be it. Fully appreciate your time!

Comment: @TezWingfield Type(s) have their own attributes. Methods have their own attributes. Two different sets of attributes. They aren't "connected". If you want to speed up, you can cache the found method somewhere. That is possible, but is another problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example would be:

```
public static string GetContent(Type type, string controllerName) 
{
    foreach (MethodInfo method in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        ControllerNameAttribute controller = (ControllerNameAttribute)method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ControllerNameAttribute));

        if (controller == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (controller.Name != controllerName)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (method.IsGenericMethod)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        if (method.GetParameters().Length != 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        if (method.ReturnType != typeof(string))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        string result = (string)method.Invoke(null, null);
        return result;
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

You use it like:

```
string result = GetContent(typeof(Program), "blog");
```

Where `Program` is the class where the method should be.

Note that, as written, this code will work only on `static` methods. If you want to use instance methods, change it to:

```
public static string GetContent(object instance, string controllerName) 
{
    Type type = instance.GetType();

    foreach (MethodInfo method in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        ControllerNameAttribute controller = (ControllerNameAttribute)method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ControllerNameAttribute));

        if (controller == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (controller.Name != controllerName)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (method.IsGenericMethod)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        if (method.GetParameters().Length != 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        if (method.ReturnType != typeof(string))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        string result = (string)method.Invoke(instance, null);
        return result;
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

In general, both methods don't check if there is a single method with the given `controllerName`. They simply execute the first one that is found. It is possible to do even the checking, normally using LINQ, but I wanted to keep the `foreach` cycle simple and linear, and show all the other checks that should be done.

Comment: Is there any reason why you add the "Type" as a param in the method and not declaring in the method body? Also what's the purpose of (outside of the loop) : throw new InvalidOperationException(); ? Left over code?

Comment: @TezWingfield It wasn't clear if you have a single class with all the methods, or if there are multiple classes that can be "selected" in some way, or that the used class depends on the "zone" of the code you are. The `throw new InvalidOperationException();` will be done if you did wrong coding. If for example the marked method doesn't have the right signature, or if there is no valid method (the last one, outside the `foreach`).

Comment: I re-worked the above solution to learn from it and got my own version working. I'm marking this one as answered due to the inclusion of "throwing exceptions". Great work thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Code sample**

```
public class MyClass
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("my test method")]
    public bool TestMethod(string input)
    {
        return input == "OK";
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("my second method")]
    public string TestMethod2(string input)
    {
        return input;
    }

    public void Invoke(string displayName)
    {
        // attribute type we search
        Type attributeType = typeof(System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute);

        // find method
        var methodInfo = (from e in this.GetType().GetMethods()
                          let attributes = e.GetCustomAttributes(attributeType).Cast<System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute>().ToArray()
                          where attributes.Length != 0 &&
                                attributes.Any(x => string.Equals(x.DisplayName, displayName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                          select e).FirstOrDefault();

        if (methodInfo != null)
        {
            // method found
            Console.WriteLine("Invoke {0} method: {1}", methodInfo.Name, methodInfo.Invoke(this, new object[] { "OK" }));
        }
    }
}
```

**Comments**

1. `this.GetType().GetMethods()` - get all methods, you can specify which kind of methods your want to return by `BindingFlags`.
2. `e.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute))` - get all attributes of specified type
3. `methodInfo.Invoke(this, new object[] { "OK" })` - method invocation, `this` - class instance (`null` for static methods), `new object[] { "OK" }` - array of arguments.

Comment: Whilst this should work it is horrible to read. The loop posted from OP fits better I guess.

Comment: I love query syntax haha...Just reviewing both answers and learning from them before I award the answer. I never like to "Copy & Paste" more understand first.